# Flutter Mobile: Bluetooth scanner "bounces" keyboard on mobile

Tags: android, flutter, dart, barcode-scanner, samsung-mobile

I have a flutter app running with a Bluetooth barcode scanner, which is being used as keyboard input. For some reason the keyboard seems to "hide" and "show" for every character in the barcode I scan, so about 10 times a scan. It also resizes my widgets over and over since the keyboard continuously shows and hides. I've found that this behavior only shows up on Samsung devices (S10, tablet so far).